# tomcat 8 security Form based authentification auto-login

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, forms-authentication

I am using tomcat 8 form base authentication security for my application. In `web.xml`:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login-failed.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

**Is there a way to pass `username` & `password` to `login.jsp` directly through URL `POST/GET`?**

I am trying to connect my application to another application and as such I would like the users to be able to login directly without having to type the credentials again. As such, I am passing the username and credential through a post request to `login.jsp` from my master application:

```
<script language="javascript">
<%
String username= (String)request.getParameter("username");
String password= (String)request.getParameter("password");
System.out.println("username========="+((String)username));
System.out.println("password========="+((String)password));

%>
function autologin(){
    document.forms[0].j_username.value = "<%=username%>";
    document.forms[0].j_password.value = "<%=password%>";
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
</script>

<body onload = "javascript:autologin()">
<form method="POST" name="loginform" action="j_security_check">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Loading.......</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="j_username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="j_password"/ ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="hidden" value="Go" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
```

My aim was to pass the credentials like this:

http://localhost:8080/myApp/login.jsp?username=user&password=password

But I am getting the following error:

> HTTP Status 400 - Invalid direct reference to form login page

However, the username and password are getting printed correctly meaning they are passed. **Apparently, we cannot access the login form directly.**
So are there any workaround or if there is some thing incorrect/missing from my code?

**Edit 1:**

The form.submit() in the javascript works. I tried hard-coding the username & password in the `login.jsp` page:

```
<%
String username="user";
String password="password";
%>
```

And then, directly hitting http://localhost:8080/myApp/ takes me to the application. The only problem is that I cannot access `login.jsp` page directly from the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I gather, one simply can't  point a browser at the login page because there's no way to tell it where to got next! The login page's action is a builtin process, not a servlet or `JSP` that could then move you along to the next page.

The idea behind the login facility is that since a user can jump into any part of a webapp that has a distinct URL, thus bypassing a login page, the whole login process is moved external to the webapp so that if someone addresses the webapp and they are not yet logged in, the original URL is intercepted, the login form is presented, and if (and ONLY if) the login succeeds will the original URL be presented.
 Hence, we directly cannot pass variables directly or go directly to `login.jsp` through the URL. The tomcat itself redirects to the login form (mentioned in the `web.xml`) when the application is accessed if the user is not logged-in.

However, in this case, I found a workaround. Instead of passing the parameters to the login page, passing it to the application directly like this:

http://localhost:8080/myApp/?username=user&password=password

lets us login to the application directly without having to manually type in the credentials in the form. The same can be passed via a `POST` request from a different application.